# Convert negative y axis to positive (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot bar chart for some parameters for men and women. I have done like this:
[image]

I want to show the frequency for mean in upper side (positive y axis) and for women in lower side (negative x-axis). In this case, for frequency only the magnitude matter and sign does not. Just for convenience I am showing one in upper side and another in lower side. Can I change the labeling (-5, -10, ... here) in negative y-axis so that their magnitude remain same but all are positive (5, 10,...) . Now there should be two positive y-axis , one mirror image of other.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure it can be done.  Here's an example that you can play around with:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
y = np.sin(x)
ax.plot(x,y)
ax.set_yticklabels([str(abs(x)) for x in ax.get_yticks()])
ax.show()
```

Here I just set the yticklabel to be the absolute value of the y position.  Of course, I have symmetric data and you don't.  If you want it to be "mirrored" down the middle, you'll need to set an explicit y range with `ax.set_ylim`

Comment: This code gives the error `TypeError: bad operand type for abs(): 'Text'`

Comment: @DurgaDatta -- Sorry.  Copy/paste error.  I should have been iterating over `ax.get_yticks()`, not `ax.get_yticklabels` :)

Comment: This answers my question, I am able to get the necessary effect now. Thank you. One doubt: if I do `fig = plt.figure()` and use `fig.set_yticklabels([str(abs(x)) for x in fig.get_yticks()])`, it give error. Why is it necessary to use subplot, even when only single figure is involved?

Comment: @DurgaDatta -- You need to create an axes instance.  There's another convenience function for creating a figure and axes at once, but I can't remember what it is right now...

Comment: And if you are wondering how to get the `ax` from the `plt`, use the helper function `ax = plt.gca()`