# Improve ticking and grid using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I have the following code:

```
import datetime
from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter
from pylab import *

hits=array([100,250,130,290])
misses=array([13,18,105,15])
X = np.arange(len(hits))

base=datetime.date(2014, 8, 1)
date_list=array([base + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0,len(hits))])

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,1,1,figsize=(15,10))

bar_handles=[]
for i in range(len(hits)):
    bar_handles.append(
        ax.barh(
            -X[i],hits[i],facecolor='#89E07E', edgecolor='white',
            align='center',label="Impressions"))
    bar_handles.append(
        ax.barh(-X[i],-misses[i],facecolor='#F03255', edgecolor='white',
                align='center',label="Misses"))

for i in range(len(bar_handles)):
    patch = bar_handles[i].get_children()[0]
    bl = patch.get_xy()
    percent_x = 0.5*patch.get_width() + bl[0]
    percent_y = 0.5*patch.get_height() + bl[1]
    percentage=0
    if i%2==0:
        j=i/2
        percentage = 100*(float(hits[j])/float(hits[j]+misses[j]))
    else:
        j=(i-1)/2
        percentage = 100*(float(misses[j])/float(hits[j]+misses[j]))
    ax.text(percent_x,percent_y,"%d%%" % percentage,ha='center',va='center')

for i in range(len(hits)):
    plt.yticks(-X,date_list)
plt.tick_params(which='both', width=0)

max_hits_num=round(np.amax(hits),-2)
max_miss_num=round(np.amax(misses),-2)
xticks=np.arange(-max_miss_num,max_hits_num,50)
minorLocator = FixedLocator(xticks)
majorLocator = FixedLocator([0])
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(majorLocator)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(minorLocator)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%d'))

ax.yaxis.grid(False)
ax.xaxis.grid(b=True,which='minor', color='0.5', linestyle='-',linewidth=1)
ax.xaxis.grid(b=True,which='major', color='b', linestyle='-',linewidth=2.5)

# ax2 = plt.twinx()
# ax2.grid(False)
# for i in range(len(hits)):
#     plt.yticks(-X,hits+misses)

plt.show()
```

This generates the following image:

[image]

I am left with one big issue and two minor problems. The big issue is that I want to add on the right y-axis the sums of the values. That is add 113,268,235 and 305. Trying something along the lines of `twinx` or `share` a `subplots` did not work out for me.

The minor issues are:

1. On the x-axis, the values to the left of `0` should be without the minus sign.
2. <s>If you look closely, you see the the blue major vertical grid line coincides with a gray minor one. Would be nice to have only the blue one.</s> This can be solved by first finding the index of `0` in `xticks` using `numpy.where` and then removing this element using `numpy.delete`.

Comment: For minor issue 1: 

If you are using python, you can actually fix this within your script when creating the figure. 

    `ax.set_xticklabels([str(abs(y)) for y in ax.get_xticklabels()])`

I believe this should work, basically you are using absolute value while setting the axis. I knew I saw this somewhere else! Maybe this question can help? [Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20393663/convert-negative-y-axis-to-positive-matplotlib)